# Linking index of two or more listboxes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm doing an project and there is an requirment that i haven't come up with the solution yet.
I'm asked to create a result storing system for a long jump competion. I have to create three listboxes to store attempt numbers, results (in metters) and the corresponding points to each results. However, i can only give them one textbox to enter the results, attempt numbers and points must be calculated automatically and each athlete must have 4 results.

There are two things i would like to ask you guys:

1. If the user has entered something wrong, he/she should be allowed to delete one or all results. And when a result is deleted, all attempt number and point related to that result should be deleted as well. Clearing all is fine with me but only delete one from the list is not really. So how can i solve this problem.
2. The listbox containing attempt numbers should be in order (1, 2, 3, and 4). I can make the listbox to generate those numbers if the user enters all results in numerical order. HOwever, the problem is that he/she can delete ramdomly selected item. If he/she deleted attempt number 3 for instance, the next result added should have the attempt 3 back instead of attempt 5. And the new added result should move to position between 2 and 4 rather staying at the bottom.

I hope you can understand what i'm trying to say. Sorry about my explaination, English is not my native language.

All of your ansers are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the item to delete with the listbox, and then remove as Farhan Sabir has said. You could then force the user to re-enter the distance for the attempt they have just deleted as the next value.

If you only have one textbox to enter the results, you could use a label to indicate which attempt they are entering (set it to automatically change to the number of items in the list +1 after entering a ditance). This would Indicate to the user that they have to re-enter a deleted distance straight after they have deleted one. A messagebox could help prompt this as well.

I am not sure how you would change competitor, but you have not mentioned that at all within your question.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you got the index of the selected item (as Farhan Sabir suggestion above), you can delete the item of the other 2 listbox base on that index. Then you may try the [listbox1.Items.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.insert.aspx) to insert the item to specific index of the listbox. however, i think you would have to ask the user the input of the attempt number along with the attempt result in order to add it back to the list with right order